# Верстка под opencart

Tags: html, css, opencart

Как нормально заверстать под opencart, кэш достал, чистить постоянно приходиться, чтобы увидеть результат.

Кэш на сервере в папках, а не браузерный.

Прислали верстку html/css, сейчас надо впихнуть эту верстку на сайт, но кэш все портит.

Comment: Чистить кэш  :)  Какой opencart используете ? Версию

Comment: Версия там стоит последняя. Есть там /storage/cache, но что сделать, чтобы не приходилось постоянно чистить его? Может отключить как-то возможно, ну чисто на время.

Comment: в opencart 3 есть возможность отключения Кэширования, в правом верхнем углу кнопка "Шестеренка" синяя, на нее нажмите и там посмотрите настройки.

Comment: Спасибо, вечером проверю